# How to change all values in a Dictionary<string, bool>?

Tags: c#, linq, loops, dictionary, enumeration

So I have a `Dictionary<string, bool>` and all I want to do is iterate over it and set all values to false in the dictionary. What is the easiest way to do that?

I tried this:

```
foreach (string key in parameterDictionary.Keys)
    parameterDictionary[key] = false;
```

However I get the error: "Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute."

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Just change the enumeration source to something other than the dictionary.

```
foreach (string key in parameterDictionary.Keys.ToList())
  parameterDictionary[key] = false;
```

---

For .net 2.0

```
foreach (string key in new List<TKey>(parameterDictionary.Keys))
  parameterDictionary[key] = false;
```

Comment: Gah, it's always something so simple. Duh; it must be late. Thank you! Will accept in 12 minutes when I am able :)

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not safe to do if keys are being added by a background thread.

Comment: @kami ToList is an extension method defined on System.Linq.Enumerable, which is .net 3.5.  You'll need to find another way to create an extra collection to use as an enumeration source.

Answer (score 5):

In .NET 5 the following snippet no longer throws:

```
var d = new Dictionary<string, int> { { "a", 0 }, { "b", 0 }, { "c", 0 }};

foreach (var k in d.Keys){
    d[k] = 1;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Sometimes you'll come aross this while using `foreach` and `.ForEach` loops. Using a for loop allows you to use the dictionary's own key collection:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < parameterDictionary.Count; ++i) {
        var kvp = parameterDictionary.ElementAt(i); // using System.Linq;
        parameterDictionary[kvp.Key] = false;
    }
```

** EDIT **

It *seems* people are upset about my answer although I have no idea way so I wrote a fiddle to back up my code:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/U9EsNO

Notes

- trying to edit a dictionary's own values in a foreach will result in `InvalidOperationException`
- you see I combat that error with a for loop
- it is always completely acceptable to copy your keycollection to another variable

** EDIT 2 **

Thx to @DStanley I understand more about the downvotes and have edited my answer appropriately. Happy coding!

Comment: You still need to "copy" the keys to a collection that supports an indexer. `foreach` would work just as well here since you're iterating over a copy of the key collection instead of the dictionary itself.

Comment: @DStanley because of how foreach iterates you run into the same issue. https://dotnetfiddle.net/U9EsNO

Comment: The fiddle does not match your answer - in your answer you are making a copy of the key collection and iterating over that with a for loop. You could just as easily iterate over it with a `foreach` loop.  Your fiddle uses a different method which _is_ a viable alternative to a foreach.

Comment: @DStanley I see the connection now, thank you for the explanation. Answer updated.